# Yfinance Data converting to CSV files

Tags: python, csv, yfinance

The following Text gives just doesnt give any ouput, neither an error

```
with open('datasets/symbols.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            if "," not in line:
                continue
            symbol = line.split(",")[0]
            data = yf.download(symbol, start="2022-01-01", end="2022-04-24")
            data.to_csv('datasets/daily{}'.format(symbol))
```

Comment: This code should generate a file. It's not written to "print output"

Comment: Hey, first of all, did you check if your symbols (in symbols.csv) can be found in yahoo fin ? Because the tickers / symbols can be different depending on which market place you want it. Second, you can `print(symbol)` to have a feedback on if the symbol is correctly passed.